# Py2app compile app for older mac versions

Tags: python

Hi, I'm developing a python program for mac, and I get an error when I try and use the application on an older version of Mac. For example, I'm developing on mac 10.8.2 and the application is not running on 10.7.*

Is there any way to compile the program (using py2app) so that it is compatible with older mac versions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://packages.python.org/py2app/tweaking.html

This might shed some light.
You'll need to specify what platforms the application will run on otherwise it will default to the runtime libraries for your current OSX release (might be 64 bit for instance and old time macs with 32bit can't run it (as a rough example))

The same principle goes for Py2exe which does the same thing but for Windows binaries.
If you compile it on Win7, and try to run the binary on a XP machine, you'll get missing runtime dll libraries. Then you have to choices, either compile it within the app/exe or ship the runtimes with the application alongside the binary.

What you're mainly looking for in Py2app is the --resource parameter.
http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html#option-reference

`--resource <comma separated list of resources>` which will include not source code but libaries, images and whatever it is you need to ship to older platforms.

Comment: Would it be easier to compile on an older version of Mac, because i can do that, if need be

Comment: @JackRenshaw Then you run the risk of getting a inversed problem, where your runtimes on the newer machine is missing IF the operating system doesn't take this into consideration, which.. they should, at least Windows does and see how much disk-space that takes :P

Comment: Okay, specifically, what resources do i need to ship to 10.7.2 I don't know what runtime library they're using

Comment: I'm a Unix developer, after that a Windows developer.. and last but not least I've done **some** development for OSX, can't say i know the resources out of the hat, google around on the error that you get? Which, you havn't mentioned btw :P

Comment: You see, i'm developing for very restricted machines, so i can't use console to debug. I'm not getting any errors, just Error: MYAPP